# Relation between radius of smallest sphere containing a n-dimensional simplex and its edge length

Tags: geometry, simplex

I have a $n$-dimensional simplex with maximum edge length equal to $l$. Do we have a relationship between radius of minimum volume sphere (thus minimum radius sphere) containing the simplex and maximum edge length "$l$".
Also is there a relationship between volume of the simplex and volume of minimum sphere (in terms of radius) containing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, one can bound the radius of the minimal enclosing sphere by the largest edge length.

For any $n \ge 1$ and $n$-simplex $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with vertices $v_1, \ldots, v_{n+1}$. Let

- $\ell_{ij} = \| v_i - v_j \|$ be the edge lengths.
- $\ell_{\rm max} = \max\limits_{i<j} \ell_{ij}$ be the longest edge length.
- $\bar{B}(c,r) = \{ v \in \mathbb{R}^n : \| v - c \| \le r \}$ be the closed ball centered at $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with radius $r$.
- $r_{\rm min}$ be the smallest $r$ such that there is a $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with
  $S \subset \bar{B}(c,r)$.

We have

$$\bbox[border:1px solid blue;padding: 8px;]{r_{min} \le \sqrt{\frac{n}{2(n+1)}} \ell_{\rm max}}\tag{*1}$$

This is a special case of [Jung's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jung's_theorem).

> For any compact set $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, let $d = \max_{p,q \in K} \| p - q \|$ be its diameter.  Jung's theorem states that one can find a closed ball $\bar{B}(c,r)$ containing $K$ with radius $r \le  \sqrt{\frac{n}{2(n+1)}} d$.

Look at [here](https://matthewhr.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/hellys-theorem-and-applications-ii-jungs-theorem/) for one way of proving this more general result.

---

**TL;DR**

For my own benefit of understanding this stuff, following is a proof of $(*1)$.

We will prove $(*1)$ by induction in $n$.

The base case $n = 1$ is trivial. For any $n > 1$, let us assume above statement is true for all dimension $1 \le m  < n$.

Let $\varphi_S : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function: $\;\;\varphi_{S}(v) = \max\limits_{i} \| v - v_i \|^2$.
Since $S$ is convex, for any closed ball $\bar{B}(c,r)$, we have
$$S \subset \bar{B}(c,r) 
\quad\iff\quad \text{ all }v_i \in \bar{B}(c,r)
\quad\iff\quad
\text{ all }\| v_i - c \| \le r
\quad\iff\quad \varphi_S(c) \le r^2
$$
The problem of finding $r_{min}$ is equivalent to minimizing the function $\varphi_S(v)$.

1. $\varphi_S(v)$ achieve its minimum at some unique $c_{\rm min}$ with $r_{\rm min}^2 = \varphi_S(c_{\rm min})$.

   For each $i$, $\| v - v_i \|^2$ is strictly convex and continuous in $v$. Being pointwise maximum of these sort of functions, $\varphi_S(v)$ is strictly convex and continuous too. Since $\varphi_S(v)$ is bounded from below and blows up as $\| v \| \to \infty$. $\varphi_S(v)$ achieve its absolute minimum at some unique point $c_{\rm min}$.
2. $c_{\rm min} \in S$.

   $S$ is the intersection of $n+1$ closed half spaces supported at their faces. For $v \notin S$, $v$ belongs to at least one of the complement of these closed 
   half space. If one move $v$ towards $S$ along the normal direction of the corresponding face, all $\| v - v_i \|^2$ will be decreased. As a result, $\varphi_S(v)$ will be decreased and $v$ cannot be $c_{\rm min}$.
3. If $c_{\rm min} \in \partial S$, then $c_{\rm min}$ belongs to some
   $m$-face $S'$ of $S$ with $m < n$. By induction assumption, we will have
   $$r_{min} \le \sqrt{\frac{m}{2(m+1)}}\ell_{max}(S') < \sqrt{\frac{n}{2(n+1)}}\ell_{max}(S)$$
4. Otherwise, $c_{\rm min} \in {\rm int}\,S$ and $\| c_{\rm min} - v_i \| = r_{\rm min}$ for all $i$.

   Let $I$ be the set of vertices at a distance $r_{\rm min}$ from $c_{\rm min}$. It is clear $I$ contains at least two vertices. If $I$ does not exhaust all vertices, then $c_{\rm min}$ need to belong to the hyperplane span by vertices in $I$. If not, we can reduce $\| v - v_i \|$ for $v_i \in I$ by moving $v$ from $c_{\rm min}$ towards that hyperplane while keeping $\| v - v_j \| < r_{\rm min}$ for those $v \notin I$. This contradicts with the minimality of $c_{\rm min}$.
   If $c_{\rm min}$ do belong to that hyperplane, it will belong to $\partial S$.
   This contradicts with the assumption $c_{\rm min} \in {\rm int}\,S$. As a result, $I$ contains all vertices.

   Since $c_{\rm min} \in {\rm int}\,S$, there exists $n+1$ numbers $\lambda_i$ such that
   $$c_{\rm min} = \sum_{i}\lambda_i v_i \quad\text{ with }\quad\begin{cases}
   \lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_{n+1} > 0\\
   \sum\limits_{i} \lambda_i = 1
   \end{cases}$$

   These are the [barycentric coordiantes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) of $c_{\rm min}$ with respect to simplex $S$.

   Recall for any two points $u, v \in S$ with barycentric coordinates $\mu_i, \nu_i$, their distance is given by following formula:
   $$\| u - v \|^2 = - \sum_{i<j} \ell_{ij}^2(\mu_i - \nu_i)(\mu_j - \nu_j)$$

   Apply this to $c_{\rm min}$ and vertex $v_k$, we have
   $$r_{\rm min}^2 = \| c_{\rm min} - v_k\|^2
   = -\sum_{i<j}\ell_{ij}^2(\lambda_i - \delta_{ki})(\lambda_j - \delta_{kj})
   = \sum_{i\ne k}\ell_{ki}^2\lambda_i - \frac12\sum_{i,j}\ell_{ij}^2\lambda_i\lambda_j$$

   Multiply by $\lambda_k$ and sum over $k$, we obtain
   $$r_{\rm min}^2 = \frac12\sum_{i,j} \ell_{ij}^2\lambda_i\lambda_j
   \quad\implies\quad
   2 r_{\rm min}^2 = \sum_{i\ne k}\ell_{ki}^2\lambda_i,\;\forall k$$

   Sum over $k$ again, we obtain
   $$2(n+1)r_{\rm min}^2 = \sum_{k,i}\ell_{k,i}^2\lambda_i \le n\ell_{\rm max}^2\sum_i\lambda_i = n\ell_{\rm max}^2$$

Combine step $3$. and $4$., $(*1)$ is true for this $n$ and by principle of induction, it is true for all $n \ge 1$.

---

Answer (score 1):

Calculations are known for the circumscribed hypersphere,<sup>1</sup>
but as 
*achillehui* pointed out, this is in general different from the minimum radius enclosing sphere. In the literature, your problem is often called
the *Minimum Enclosing Ball* (MEB) problem. This has been studied extensively
for enclosing arbitrary points (rather than just the vertices of a simplex).
It is an LP-type problem, and that is how it is usually solved: via linear programming. Below is a reference<sup>2</sup> that gives background and
citations on the problem. Note from this paper that an exact algorithm
due to Gärtner is built into CGAL.

---

> <sup>1</sup>
>   [A formula for the N-circumsphere of an N-simplex](https://westy31.home.xs4all.nl/Circumsphere/ncircumsphere.htm), by G.Westendorp.
>
> <sup>2</sup>
>   Kumar, Piyush, Joseph SB Mitchell, and E. Alper Yildirim. "Comuting Core-Sets and Approximate Smallest Enclosing HyperSpheres in High Dimensions." *ALENEX*. 2003. ([PDF download](http://www.siam.org/meetings/alenex03/Abstracts/Pkumar2.PDF).)